# How can I specify the schema to run an sql file against in the Postgresql command line

Tags: postgresql

I run scripts against my database like this...

```
psql -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile.sql
```

The only problem is I want to be able to specify in this command what schema to run the script against.  I could call set search_path='my_schema_01' but the files are supposed to be portable.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 97):

You can create one file that contains the `set schema ...` statement and then include the actual file you want to run:

Create a file `run_insert.sql`:

```
set schema 'my_schema_01';
\i myInsertFile.sql
```

Then call this using:

```
psql -d myDataBase -a -f run_insert.sql
```

Answer (score 91):

More universal way is to set search_path (should work in PostgreSQL 7.x and above):

```
SET search_path TO myschema;
```

Note that `set schema myschema` is an alias to above command that is **not** available in 8.x.

See also: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: I prefer this answer, as you can set the search path to more than one schema - handy if you're using schemas as they are intended.

Answer (score 58):

**Main Example**

The example below will run *myfile.sql* on database *mydatabase* using schema *myschema*.

```
psql "dbname=mydatabase options=--search_path=myschema" -a -f myfile.sql
```

The way this works is the first argument to the [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) command is the *dbname* argument. The docs mention a [connection string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) can be provided.

> If this parameter contains an = sign or starts with a valid URI prefix
> (postgresql:// or postgres://), it is treated as a conninfo string

The [dbname keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) specifies the database to connect to and the [options keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) lets you specify command-line options to send to the server at connection startup. Those options are detailed in the [server configuration chapter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config.html). The option we are using to select the schema is [search_path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html).

**Another Example**

The example below will connect to host *myhost* on database *mydatabase* using schema *myschema*. The `=` special character must be url escaped with the escape sequence `%3D`.

```
psql postgres://myuser@myhost?options=--search_path%3Dmyschema
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, having already created large file without the schema specified.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - I wanted to create an alias on my machine to connect directly to a database set the search_path and this worked like a charm.

Comment: In the "Another example", you forgot to include the name of the database in the URI.
It should be `psql postgres://myuser@myhost/mydatabase?options=--search_path%3Dmyschema`

Answer (score 18):

The `PGOPTIONS` environment variable may be used to achieve this in a flexible way.

In an Unix shell:

```
PGOPTIONS="--search_path=my_schema_01" psql -d myDataBase -a -f myInsertFile.sql
```

If there are several invocations in the script or sub-shells that need the same options, it's simpler to set `PGOPTIONS` only once and export it.

```
PGOPTIONS="--search_path=my_schema_01"
export PGOPTIONS

psql -d somebase
psql -d someotherbase
...
```

or invoke the top-level shell script with `PGOPTIONS` set from the outside

```
PGOPTIONS="--search_path=my_schema_01"  ./my-upgrade-script.sh
```

In Windows CMD environment, `set PGOPTIONS=value` should work the same.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using something like this and works very well:* :-)

```
(echo "set schema 'acme';" ; \
  cat ~/git/soluvas-framework/schedule/src/main/resources/org/soluvas/schedule/tables_postgres.sql) \
  | psql -Upostgres -hlocalhost quikdo_app_dev
```

**Note:** Linux/Mac/Bash only, though probably there's a way to do that in Windows/PowerShell too.

Comment: Worked for me. Make sure wrap with bracket as shown.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
psql postgresql://myuser:password@myhost/my_db -f myInsertFile.sql
```

Comment: The part `my_schema_01` after the slash is in fact the name of the database and not schema.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to add schema to a file dynamically so that whatever schema name user will provide from the cli, I will run sql file with that provided schema name.
For this, I replaced some text in the sql file. First I added `{{schema}}` in the file like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION {{schema}}.usp_dailygaintablereportdata(
```

then replace `{{schema}}` dynamically with user provided schema name with the help of `sed` command

```
sed -i "s/{{schema}}/$pgSchemaName/" $filename
result=$(psql -U $user -h $host -p $port -d $dbName -f "$filename" 2>&1)
sed -i "s/$pgSchemaName/{{schema}}/" $filename
```

First replace is done, then target file is run and then again our replace is reverted back

Answer (score -2):

I was facing similar problems trying to do some dat import on an intermediate schema (that later we move on to the final one). As we rely on things like extensions (for example PostGIS), the "run_insert" sql file did not fully solved the problem.

After a while, we've found that at least with Postgres 9.3 the solution is far easier... just create your SQL script **always specifying the schema when refering to the table**:

`CREATE TABLE "my_schema"."my_table" (...);
 COPY "my_schema"."my_table" (...) FROM stdin;`

This way using `psql -f xxxxx`  works perfectly, and you don't need to change search_paths nor use intermediate files (and won't hit extension schema problems).