# Postgres - Unable to execute SQL script, ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, schema, junit5, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to execute a SQL script on the different schema in spring boot. However, I got the following errors:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [sql/init.sql]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authorities ( username varchar(255) NOT NULL, authority varchar(50) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_users FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES users(username) ); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
  Position: 28
```

`init.sql`

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authorities (
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    authority varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_users
        FOREIGN KEY(username)
            REFERENCES users(username)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS sequence_username_id START WITH 500000000;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN attempts DROP NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN usernameid SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN usernameid SET DEFAULT nextval('sequence_username_id'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN externalthirdpartyuserflag SET DEFAULT false;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN passwordtemporaryflag SET DEFAULT false;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN activated SET DEFAULT false;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

`BaseIntegrationTest.java`

```java
  . . .
  @Value("${dynamic-schema}")
  private String dynamicSchema;

  protected void executeSqlFile(String sqlFileName) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("SET search_path TO \"" + dynamicSchema + "\"");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("grant usage on schema public to public");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("grant create on schema public to public");
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(sqlFileName);
    ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resource);
    databasePopulator.execute(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
  }
```

`applications.properties`

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2dll.create_namespaces=true
hibernate.default_schema=${dynamic-schema}
. . .
dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${dynamic-database}?currentSchema=${dynamic-schema}
dataSource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
. . .
dataSource.hikari.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=${dynamic-schema}
dataSource.hikari.username=postgres
dataSource.hikari.password=postgres
dataSource.hikari.autoCommit=false
datasource.hikari.schema=${dynamic-schema}
. . .
dynamic-schema=MySchema
```

`AuthDataSourceConfiguration.java`

```java
  . . .
  private Properties getJpaProperties(HibernateProperties hibernateProperties) {
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    . . .
    jpaProperties.put("javax.persistence.create-database-schemas", true);

    return jpaProperties;
  }
```

I have tried these solutions, but it still produces the same errors.

- [How can I specify the schema to run an sql file against in the Postgresql command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770944/how-can-i-specify-the-schema-to-run-an-sql-file-against-in-the-postgresql-comman)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/error-no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in
- [how to properly specify database schema in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430422/how-to-properly-specify-database-schema-in-spring-boot)

I tried changing the schema name to `public` and it's working. However, I still haven't figured out why it's not working for another schema name.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried changing the schema name to lowercase and the issue still persists. The error message is still the same.

Comment: That was just a guess...